# EditText Android: Set color to text present in double quotes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to highlight the text present in the double quotes with blue color, inside edittext.

I have done with that like shown below.

```
          //reading file  
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

              for(char c : line.toCharArray()) {

                  edittext.append(check(c));
                  //check is a function which checks whether a double quote is present, if so it will set blue using Spannable utli it found next double quote.
               }

          }
```

Now my problem is if I have some 50 lines in my file, then my app is not at all responding.

Is there any better way to do this function.

Comment: Did you consider using something like an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Try to run it in a new thread

Comment: Better way to format your string in HTML and display it with `Html.fromHtml()` in EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class:

```
public class SetColorForEditTExt extends AsyncTask<Void, CharSequence, Void>{

    String fileName;
    EditText edittext;

    public SetColorForEditTExt(String fileName, EditText edittext) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.edittext = edittext;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String line = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {

                    onProgressUpdate(check(c));
                    //check is a function which checks whether a double quote is present, if so it will set blue using Spannable utli it found next double quote.
                }

            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(CharSequence... values) {
        if(values == null || values.length == 0){
            return;
        }

        CharSequence result = values[0];
        if(edittext != null) {
            edittext.append(result);
        }
    }

    private CharSequence check(char c){
        //do something
    }
}
```

And then use it when needed:

```
new SetColorForEditTExt(file1, edittext).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: can we append text to edittext in `doInBackground` method.

Comment: I'm not sure, but most probably not. Only main thread can interact with UI elements.